# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

So this is my first ever question and I'm new here. So I'm attending course on Udemy for javascript and this is my problem:

I define a parameter(object) before executing a function but the browser throws an error on it.
So I console.log it before executing function and it returns the data like it suppose to be,
but when using in a function it errors out that it's undefined.

After losing hope at trying to find mistake I even copy paste code from the original program from the course but it still throws mistake! So I think it's not a problem with the code but something else. Maybe you know what? Here is the code anyway.

```
const controlList = () => {
    // Create a new list IF there in none yet
    if (!state.list) state.list = new List();

    // Add each ingredient to the list and UI
    console.log(state.recipe.ingredients);
    state.recipe.ingredients.forEach(el => {
        const item = state.list.addItem(el.count, el.unit, el.ingredient);
        console.log(state.list.items);
        console.log(item);            // HERE IS OK
        listView.renderItem(item);   // THIS LINE THROWS MISTAKE
    });
}

export const renderItem = item => {
    const markup = `
        <li class="shopping__item" data-itemid=${item.id}>
            <div class="shopping__count">
                <input type="number" value="${item.count}" step="${item.count}" class="shopping__count-value">
                <p>${item.unit}</p>
            </div>
            <p class="shopping__description">${item.ingredient}</p>
            <button class="shopping__delete btn-tiny">
                <svg>
                    <use href="img/icons.svg#icon-circle-with-cross"></use>
                </svg>
            </button>
        </li>
    `;
    elements.shopping.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', markup);
};
```

// controlList() is called in the event listener
here

```
elements.recipe.addEventListener('click', e => {
if(e.target.matches('.btn-decrease, .btn-decrease *')) {
    // Decrrease button is clicked
    if (state.recipe.servings > 1) {
         state.recipe.updateServings('dec');
         recipeView.updateServingsIngredients(state.recipe);
    }
} else if (e.target.matches('.btn-increase, .btn-increase *')) {
    // Increase button is clicked
    state.recipe.updateServings('inc');
    recipeView.updateServingsIngredients(state.recipe);
} else if (e.target.matches('.recipe__btn--add, .recipe__btn--add *')) {
    // Add ingredients to shopping list
    controlList();  <---------------- HERE
}
```

});

Comment: I don't see any code that calls `controlList()`, though, can you please try to turn your problem code into a [mcve]?

Comment: Find the specific expression throwing the error. Work backwards to identify what assertion is incorrect.

Comment: I'm not seeing a definition for the `listView` object in your provided code. Where are you defining it?

Comment: listView is an import from another file where is renderItem

Answer (score 0):

Holy molly guakamolly I found whats wrong.
Turn out while importing functions from another file I didn't import correctly...
(I mean everything *)